# Why didSet is not working why initialisation.?

Tags: swift

When I am initializing it, **doStuff()** is not called, can anybody let me why it's happening and how can I call this while initialization.

For now, **doStuff()** is called only when i am changing the value of *flightTripTypeEnum*

```
var flightTripTypeEnum: FlightJourneyTypeEnum = .OneWayTrip {
                didSet{
                    doStuff()
                }
            }
```

Comment: did set is fired when the value changes, not when its initialised with a default value. This is expected behaviour

Comment: Because thats how Swift works. It didSet were called during initialization then it would greately complicate things, e.g. you would have nonoptional variables without assigned values.